# How to create a filtered search table using reactJS. Trying to get my search bar to filter the info in the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter

I am trying to get my search bar to actually filter the information in my table. I have created a both a table and a search bar but the search bar currently has no functionality. Right now I can type in the search box but nothing happens. I think this might have to do with the fact that I am using react and not just JS alone. I would simply like to be able to search by name(so the info in the first column). I am not very familiar with creating components and have looked at every tutorial and watched endless videos but have not been able to get anything to work. Anything will help, Thanks!

This is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route
            path="/list"
            exact
            strict
            render={() => {
              function myFunction() {
                var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                var td, i;

                for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                  if (td) {
                    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                      tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                      tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                  }
                }
              }

              return (
                <div>
                  <div className="spacing overflow">
                    <input
                      type="search"
                      id="myInput"
                      onsearch="myFunction()"
                      onkeyup="myFunction()"
                      placeholder="Search Here"
                    />
                    <table className="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
                      <tr>
                        <th> Name </th>
                        <th> API </th>
                        <th> Product </th>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <a href="http://localhost:3000/expert"> Expert</a>{" "}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="http://localhost:3000/list-expert">
                            Credit{" "}
                          </a>
                        </td>
                        <td> ADD NAME </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <a href="http://localhost:3000/Lex"> Lex </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="http://localhost:3000/list-lex"> Phone</a>
                        </td>
                        <td> ADD NAME </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <a href="http://localhost:3000/Lex"> Lex </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="http://localhost:3000/list-lex"> IM</a>
                        </td>
                        <td> ADD NAME </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <a href="http://localhost:3000/star"> star</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="http://localhost:3000/list-star"> Verify</a>
                        </td>
                        <td> ADD NAME </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's React, you do not need to _change_  (and you should NOT) generated DOM. Generate the table from the js data, proof of concept: `data.filter(yourFilterFunction).map((item, index) => <tr key={index}><td>{item.name}</td></tr>)`. Obviously filter text has to be somewhere in the `state` (but data may come from `state`, `props` or even hard-coded in your JS/imported module). I understand that this isn't clear enough: you should REALLY start with a tutorial about React concepts. And...well...also `render` for the router (instead of simply the `component` is uncommon...leave routing out, for now

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was simply missing { } around myFunction instead of " "
so it should look like this:

onKeyUp={myFunction}